# Navigate list item in PowerApp

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, powerapp

How to navigate sharepoint list item in powerapp.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`Navigate(*screenName*,ScreenTransition.Cover)` - Replace `*screenName*` with your actual screen name.